# Dialog displaying white background when using a png with transparency as a background

Tags: android, android-layout, png, transparency, android-dialog

I created a background for a Dialog with Gimp, and it's a PNG with transparency and transparent background. If I display it on a ImageView it's fine and the background is transparent.

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/test"
```

But if I display it as a background of the LinearLayout of my Dialog, then, a white background is displayed instead of the transparency (alpha channel) of the image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/test"

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.xmldialog);
```

This is the PNG:

[image]

What should be done to get the alpha channel and not a white background below the image I created when I use as a background of a the LinearLayout of a Dialog? I'm sure it's a problem with the dialog. Something must be setted to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it png as background of dialog `setBackgroundDrawable()`.

```
  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

If you are going with set background to root layout . then set the background as transparent .

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

And make your root layout to hold the background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/test"
```

Make sure the png used do not have any colored padding left on borders.

You can also set the Dialog background with specified theme. below is an example .

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
```

Use this theme in Dialog's constructor.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

Change the theme as per your need and watch out for attributes used .

Comment: I haven't tested it . So let me know the output .

Comment: this must be achieved with XML code, not by java code at runtime, but also your solution didn't work

Comment: Ok looks like you tried it already . Can you post the output dialog image . which is currently you are getting .

Comment: it's the same but with a white sqare behind the png i posted

Comment: omg your wolution works if i use it this way (without your "this"):  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.test)); the problem is that it requires API 21 and my app is for being used with lower api devices (at least 14) also i whould prefeer to solve this with XML code and without doing this at runtime. Why this works and not the xml parameter I used?

Comment: LOL . `this`  i used fro current Activity . ultimately uts `Context`

Comment: no, i mean the this passed as parameter to getDrawable, i deleted it. But please answer me, i whould prefeer to solve this with XML code and without doing this at runtime. Why this works and not the xml parameter I used?

Comment: Because its a property of `Dialog's` theme not the content layout . You can change it with theme also and at runtime .

Comment: how can I change this in theme instead of at runtime? thank you

Comment: What you mean instead of runtime? Dialog is creating at runtime so you need to pass the theme in constructor . That's it ..

Comment: the theme can be changed with XML?

Comment: NO . Theme will set to window not to content layout.

Answer (score 1):

Two hexadecimal characters can be appended to any hexadecimal color code. The first two characters in an 8-digit hex color code represents its opacity in Android.

The two hexadecimal characters can range from 00 to FF. For example,

-> Normal opaque black hex- "#000000"

-> Fully transparent - "#00000000"

-> Fully opaque - "#FF000000"

-> 50% transparent - "#7F000000"

This way you can change any color to any level of transparency.

To find the hexadecimal prefix from a percentage:

Divide the percentage number by 100 and multiply by 255 to get the decimal value. Convert the decimal to hexadecimal.

For example, for 50%, 50/100 * 255 = 127. Using the link we get hexadecimal value 7F.

Hope this helps you to understand to set the transparent background for any view.